# How to use GraphQL customized Authentication class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, graphql, jwt, amazon-cognito

With Django REST Framework(DRF) I can customize `Authentication class and Permission class`  simply like this

```py
from django_cognito_jwt import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class CognitoQuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

In the GraphQL [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/#). It is using standard Django login which is different from my project. I had checked with source `LoginRequiredMixin` but no luck. I don't see `Authentication class` there then I can override it

**Problem:**
How to customize GraphQL `Authentication class and Permission class` like one I did in `DRF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trials and tries with [`django-graphql-jwt`](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt) with no luck. [vinayan3](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/476) has the answer on my question. Because `django-cognito-jwt` is considered as a `DRF` complement.

**Solution:**
Just replace `TokenAuthentication` with `JSONWebTokenAuthentication` from `django_cognito_jwt`

Comment: Sounds like you should be able to use `django-graphql-jwt`s' [`@user_passes_test` decorator](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/latest/decorators.html#user-passes-test) to write custom permission verification functions.

Comment: [django-graphql-auth](https://github.com/PedroBern/django-graphql-auth) allow to register and manage user account with GraphQL.

It extends django-graphql-jwt for JWT authentication.